# IE6 floated element wrapping problеm

Tags: css, css-float, element, internet-explorer-6, word-wrap

I am trying to get  tags to wrap to the next line by left floating them. In firefox the text will wrap onto the start of the next line, however IE6 will wrap the text onto the line directly under the start of the text of the tag. So for example if the a tag is halfway along the line it will wrap to the next line but halfway along it instead of wrapping to the start.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get the wrapping to begin at the start of the line?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you may try looking at the `<nobr>` tag.

From [utoronto.ca](http://www.utoronto.ca/web/HTMLdocs/NewHTML/wbr.html):

> NOBR marks a block of text that should not contain line breaks -- line breaks are forbidden, an the text will be presented as a single line, without any word wrapping. This is useful for text that you do not wish broken at word spaces, regardless of the page layout.

Here are a few resources:

- [HTML NOBR - HTML Code Tutorial](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linepar/_NOBR.html)
- [MSDN Article - noBR Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535856%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [NOBR and WBR Elements](http://www.utoronto.ca/web/HTMLdocs/NewHTML/wbr.html)